# Breaking a string in python if a number is 5 digit long or longer

Tags: python, regex, string

I know I can break a string in python using:

```
s = re.split("[0-9]|  ", string)[0].strip()
```

However, I would like to break the string only if I have 5 or more consecutive digits.

Ex.

```
Hello1234 => Hello1234
Hello12345 => Hello
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If input is `Hello12345World` do you want `['Hello', 'World']` in output?

Comment: No, just Hello.

Comment: did you try my annswer?

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks!

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like

```
s = re.split("[0-9]{5,}", string)[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also use `re.sub` to remove everything after 5 digits:

```
>>> re.sub('[0-9]{5,}.*', '', 'Hello12345World')
'Hello'

>>> re.sub('[0-9]{5,}.*', '', 'Hello12345')
'Hello'

>>> re.sub('[0-9]{5,}.*', '', 'Hello1234')
'Hello1234'
```

Answer (score 0):

(\D)*(?=\d{5,})

matches any string with 5 digits+

the first capture group will match your string without the digits

http://regexr.com/ 
will allow you to test regular expressions, and also has a reference guide